# Is it appropriate to provide example code for someone else's question?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I went to post a question last night, but quickly realised it was a duplicate of another question. I offered a bounty on the question to draw attention to it, and someone quickly asked that I provide an MVCE showing the problem.

I'm not totally sure what's appropriate in this situation.

- On the one hand, an MVCE would definitely benefit the question and make it easier to get a strong, definitive answer.
- However, this isn't my question, and it's possible that an example relevant to me won't be relevant to the OP.

Since I can't post my own example without the question being marked as a duplicate, what is the best course of action here?

Comment: thats the bad thing about putting a bounty on someone else's question: it is hard for potential answerers to communicate, ask for clarification, more code etc etc etc.  Unless it is an *identical* problem adding code can be problematic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its truly a *reproducible* problem, and the OP didn't provide any code, I would edit the example in.

Something like:

> -- old post --
>
> The following code will reproduce this issue:
>
> -- code --

If you are *really* concerned, just be clear about the source

> -- old post --
>
> The following code from @BiscuitBaker will reproduce this issue:
>
> -- code --

You never want to edit or add to OP code, since it can hide the problem. However, in this instance, there is no code to mess up. Adding an example that shows the problem can only help as far as I'm concerned.

As a total aside, while you acted correctly, if there was some way to set it up so that you could ask *your* question and the other question be a duplicate of it would seem to be a better/fairer way of doing it.

Comment: Granted, this is easier to do with full editing privileges. Just make sure your comment is *really* good (which it should be anyways) to get through the review queue.