# Can we add example code to an answer? Should we?

Tags: discussion, answers

Say someone asks a question related to HTML/CSS/JavaScript (something that can be done in a code snippet). Someone answers with a line of code that solves the problem.

Is editing the answer to include a code snippet showing the solution in action 1) allowed and 2) a good idea?

I know [SO doesn't want edits that don't actually change the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271506/should-we-edit-our-old-posts-to-include-stack-snippets?lq=1). The answer here suggests [adding code where none exists is OK](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286510/is-it-appropriate-to-provide-example-code-for-someone-elses-question) but that's in reference to a question, not an answer. There was another similar question on Meta (though it was related to adding code to the question, sorry I can't find it now) that said the likelyhood of changing the OP's intent was too high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not be adding entirely new content to another user's answer.  You can post your own answer (attributing appropriately if you are building on another user's content) if you have your own original content to add.  Alternatively you could comment on their post asking them to add additional information if you feel that it is lacking, to which they can optionally add the additional information.

Comment: Never add content which hides the actual solution. It only distracts. I agree with @Servy. Or add a jsfiddle as comment.