# Should you edit someone else's unanswered question to include examples from your own experience

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-edit

Basically a dupe of [this Meta Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286510/is-it-appropriate-to-provide-example-code-for-someone-elses-question) but it is a bit different. Also that meta question is 9 years old and opinions/best practices may have changed.

The same as the other asker I found an old unanswered question asking about my issue, and put a bounty on it.

Someone has asked for a clarification/given a suggestion in the comments.

There is example code but I could provide simplified example code, however my setup is slightly different from the original OP

[The question in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158682/jest-recommends-use-detectopenhandles-but-with-detectopenhandles-nothing-spe)

What's the best way to go about this? Is it appropriate to tag the original asker here to ask them?

Comment: Given it doesn't have an answer, i don't see a reason not to just ask another version of it. If you do receive an answer, you can link it in the comments of the old one. I'd hesitate to reach for dupe closure at that point unless an SME comes along and can confirm they're actually duplicates.

Comment: @KevinB You can't actually close a question as a dupe of another if the target doesn't have any answers. Unless the author is the same between the two posts. So there's no concern about closing as a duplicate.

Comment: *"Also that meta question is 9 years old and opinions/best practices may have changed."* - still think so? :)